# Reference multiple cells in one text box in excel?

Tags: excel, plot

I have a text box on a graph in Excel 2010 similar to the format below:

```
Some Value   X
Other Value  Y
Third Value  Z
```

Where "Some value", "Other Value", and "Third Value" are all text and X,Y,Z are numbers. Currently, that text book is all just text written in by hand. I would like to have X,Y,Z be references to cell where the values are stored instead of having to type them in. What would be the best way to accomplish having all the text in there and having X,Y,Z be references to cells with values? By best, I mean by minimizing text boxes.

Comment: So do you just want it to look at the cell to the left and say which row/column it is or do you want it to search a different sheet for that text?

Comment: The answer by Ralph below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a TextBox to reference / show the content of a cell. So, if you have a cell which contains the above table written out then you can just reference this cell and you are all done.

If there is not yet a cell which contains the above table then you can create it with references to other cells. The following is an illustration of how this could be achieved.

[image]

Just keep in mind that `Char(9)` adds the equivalent to a tab while a `Char(10)` adds a line break.